# How will android pass the MotionEvent ev)

Tags: android

In my custom view, I over-ride

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev);
```

to return `false` in some motion event,

But I want to ask another view to handle it, how can I 'forward this `MotionEvent` to the another view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

returning false from onInterceptTouch event passes the touch event down to a `ViewGroup`'s children, returning true keeps it for the `ViewGroup` itself.  See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29), their explanation for this is very detailed.